# If a cell meets a condition in a dataset, insert the ID of the Terminal that corresponds to the data

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do is insert the ATM ID's into column A for their corresponding transactions. The ID's are in the D column `(highlighted in excel example)`. For example, I'd wan't to insert `D1` into `A2-A5`, and `D6` into `A7-A10`

***Excel example:***

[image]

If the report I am formatting was always the same amount of transactions, it would be easy for me to figure out, however there are differing amount of transactions in each data set, and they change every day.

Because of this I have just been having to copy and paste the ids next to their transactions.

I'm relatively new to `VBA` so I could not figure out a way to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula. Paste it to A2 in your worksheet and copy down.

```
=IF(COUNTA($C2),LOOKUP(2,1/($D$1:$D1<>""),D:D),"")
```

To explain:-
`LOOKUP(2,1/($D$1:$D1<>""),D:D)` does the actual work.
`=IF(COUNTA($C2),[Do the job],"")` checks if C2 has something in it and writes a null string to the cell if it's blank.

After getting the appearance you want you may wish to get rid of the formulas. Use *Copy > Paste > Paste Special > Values*. for that: formulas are replaced by their values.

If you have very long columns, selecting everything is a hassle. Use the `GoTo` function for that: *Ribbon.Home > Fine & Select > GoTo > Reference = [A1:A50000]* selects the first 50,000 cells in column A.